# Изменение размеров блоком div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть много различных блоков с разными размерами. Вопрос: могу ли я изменить размер всех этих блоков, добавив их в один общий, при этом необходимо, чтобы все пропорции соблюдались

Comment: только через JS

Comment: Не подскажешь как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict'
const div = document.querySelectorAll('div');

document.querySelector('.click').addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.forEach(element => {
        element.style.width = "100px";
        element.style.height = "100px";
    })
  

});
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
<button class="click">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

можно перечислить их класс через запятую и задать стиль
можно через :nth-child()
можно задать еще так: div.father > div {}  - это задаст стиль  всем дивом что внутри